# Is there any possibility to check if the error happened?

Tags: c++, function, exception, error-handling, throw

I'm a new one working with c++ and before that I worked with pytest-python. If I wrote the tests I typed with the pytest raises etc. Is there something to check if the exception occurs? Like this pytest raises? I thought that maybe I can check this with cerr, but I think that it has different purpose. Example code:

```cpp
int compare(int a, int b) {
    if (a < 0 || b < 0) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("a or b negative");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you catch the exception, you can print it. I suggest adding the values of `a` and `b` to the exception to make it clearer though

Comment: I'm asking which function shall I use. Cerr, Catch  or  sth different?

Comment: To catch an exception you need something along the lines of `try { something that throws an exception } catch(const std::exception& ex) { std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl; }`

Comment: Choose a unit testing framework; otherwise the question is too broad. Most frameworks should provide this functionality, e.g. [GoogleTests `EXPECT_THROW`](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/assertions.html#exceptions)